# What am I doing wrong in my recursive javascript function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

I am trying to create a recursive function that filters an object, depending on the properties in the second passed argument.

Filtering works well, but my arrays are being replaced with empty objects. What could I do different so that this doesn’t occur?

```
var filter = function(obj, fields) {
  var key, o;

  if (typeof obj !== "object") { return obj;}
  o = {};
  for (key in obj) {
    if (fields[key]) {
      o[key] = filter(obj[key], fields[key]);
    }
  }
  return o;
};


data = {name: "John Doe", followers: [], notAllowedProp: false}
allowedFields = {name: true, followers: true}

console.log(filter(data, allowedFields));
// => Object { name: "John Doe", followers: {}}
```

Comment: you are returning an empty object regardless of the fields type I suggest checking the filed type and initiating o by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on a console:

```
> typeof []
"object"
```

To check for an array more robustly, you can use `Object.prototype.toString`:

```
> Object.prototype.toString.call([])
"[object Array]"
```

`Object.prototype.toString` has well-defined behavior for all native objects, and is quite reliable. Thus, for example, if you want to return anything that is not a "true" object, you could write:

```
if (Object.prototype.toString(obj) !== "[object Object]") {
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Or `[].constructor === Array`.

Comment: Although they work, there are certain [problems that can arise with those techniques](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/) that don't occur if you use `Object.prototype.toString`.

Comment: @voithos If you're not using iframes that interact with each other programmatically, you're fine using `instanceof`.

Comment: @PeterOlson: Sure, but that scenario is a plus for using `Object.prototype.toString` regardless. And from another standpoint, I'd argue that `Object.prototype.toString` is more readable than manipulating `typeof` and `instanceof`.

Comment: +1 Rather than worrying about what might and might not return correctly, I generally follow the same rules as browser detection -- basically check for features being present. i.e. a simple check for an array is `if ( obj && obj.join ){ ... }` - no other object currently supports join unless it's bespoke, to protect against bespoke false positives just check for a few more array-only functions... however if an object supports many of the methods of an array, it's probably fine to treat it like an array. imo.

Comment: @pebbl: Yes, what you're speaking of is duck typing, which is fine in most cases.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea it had a name... ty for the info :) @voithos -- any reason it's called "duck", Some far off link to testing if a witch is a witch maybe?

Comment: @pebbl: The name comes from the [duck test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test) - basically, the idea is that "if something behaves in the same manner as a duck (e.g. walks, swims, quacks), then it's probably a duck."

Comment: Right, I had not heard of that... thanks. I guess that is part of the joke with regard to Monty Python's Holy Grail - where villagers are seen weighing a witch against a duck. If she weighs the same as a duck, she must float on water because so do ducks, and therefore she is a witch. Their own version of the "duck" test ;)

Comment: Using coffeescript, I got it working at last using this `return obj if Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) isnt "[object Object]"`

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have type `object`. Consequently, you'll need to edit this line if you want to return early for arrays:

```
if (typeof obj !== "object") { return obj; }
```

There are many ways to check for an array, but this is what I would do:

```
if(typeof obj !== "object" && !(obj instanceof Array)) { return obj; }
```